# could not open buildscript class

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

I created new project in android studio and getting the following error. I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the project but problem still exists.

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not open buildscript class cache for build file '/home/rishabh/AndroidstudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build.gradle' (/home/rishabh/.gradle/caches/2.2.1/scripts/build_igdcv7jd610p8em50dpy1pra/ProjectScript/buildscript).
>   Timeout waiting to lock buildscript class cache for build file '/home/rishabh/AndroidstudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build.gradle' (/home/rishabh/.gradle/caches/2.2.1/scripts/build_igdcv7jd610p8em50dpy1pra/ProjectScript/buildscript). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
>        Owner PID: unknown
>        Our PID: 16504
>        Owner Operation: unknown
>        Our operation: Initialize cache
>        Lock file: /home/rishabh/.gradle/caches/2.2.1/scripts/build_igdcv7jd610p8em50dpy1pra/ProjectScript/buildscript/cache.properties.lock

Comment: Hello @Rishabh, Did you find any solution for above issue? I'm facing same issue but with my existing project. Can you please help me out...Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ChanchalShelar Hi, I had to re-install Android Studio for the fix.

Comment: thanks a lot and sorry for late reply :)